# LSTM wrong shape in prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have trained a model:

```
trainX = trainX.reshape(1, 43164, 17)
trainY = trainY.reshape(43164, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2, input_shape=(43164, 17)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY[0], epochs=100)

testX.shape # (8633, 17)
testX = testX.reshape(1, 8633, 17)
```

When I do a prediction for this data, I obtained an error:

```
Error when checking input: expected lstm_26_input to have shape (43164, 17) 
but got array with shape (8633, 17)
```

What can I do in order to obtaing good results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Sequential modesls](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-univariate-time-series-data-long-short-term-memory-networks/)  of Deep learning network you can either pass the data with the limited short windows with the stride of changing window or

passing all sequence with 1 dimensional vectors

```
trainX = trainX.reshape( 43164,1, 17)
trainY = trainY.reshape(43164, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2, input_shape=(1, 17)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY[0], epochs=100)

testX.shape # (8633, 17)
testX = testX.reshape(8633,1, 17)
```